# Add documentation to TL install

Tags: installing, texlive, documentation

I installed the Tex Live 20130407 on my system. To save disk space, I did not install the documentation, because I thought that `texdoc` can download those files I ask it. However, issuing

```
texdoc caption
```

throws an error:

> Sorry, no documentation found for caption. If you are unsure about the
>   name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
>   http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.

So, how can I:

- either **add the documentation to already existing TL install**;
- or **make `texdoc` download the documentation when I ask for them**?

Comment: TeX Live doesn't do "on demand download".

Comment: to add documentation to all already installed packages try issuing `tlmgr option docfiles 1` and then `tlmgr install --reinstall $(tlmgr list --only-installed | sed -e 's/^i //' -e 's/:.*$//')` Only works for UNIX systems I think.

Comment: @dcmst Since the install is fresh new, I've just re-installed everything and I'm quite happy. I therefore cannot test your idea :-/

Comment: @tohecz the command i wrote is well known, don't worry, the important thing is that you solved your problem

Comment: Then you ought to post it as an answer of course! :)

Comment: @dcmst: Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @MartinSchröder sorry, I didn't get the notification for tohecz comment, I would have made it an answer before if I had.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to add documentation files to already installed packages issuing the following commands in any terminal (both commands may need root privileges depending on how you installed Tex Live in the first place and the second is UNIX only):

```
tlmgr option docfiles 1
```

sets the docfiles option to 1, i.e. from now on `tlmgr` will download and install documentation files every time a new package is installed. If during the installation process of TeX Live the user chooses not to install docs, this option is automatically set to 0, so you need to manually change its value.

Then issue:

```
tlmgr install --reinstall $(tlmgr list --only-installed | sed -e 's/^i //' -e 's/:.*$//')
```

the above command reinstalls all packages listed by `tlmgr list --only-installed`, i.e. all already installed packages. The `sed` part is used to remove everything except the package name from the list generated by `tlmgr list --only-installed`. As an example, before the `sed` part the first line of the list looks like:

```
i 12many: Generalising mathematical index sets.
```

while after the `sed` treatment it looks like:

```
12many
```

For more info see the [`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) and [`sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) docs. Credit goes to Norbert Preining, see [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/30929) thread on comp.tex.live

Answer (score 2):

For the record, if you're using the **TeXLive Utility** GUI, you can also solve this issue by selecting the **Configure** > **Configure Documentation...**, checking the box labeled "Install documentation when updating", and confirming by clicking the **Install now** button.

[image: screenshot]

(I just ran into this issue after installing [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) and the TeXLive Utility GUI on my Mac, by runnning `brew cask install basictex tex-live-utility`.)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers in case TeX Live is installed using `apt` packages for Ubuntu (instead of a vanilla install using scripts from http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html): there are separate documentation packages available (to be installed with `apt`). From https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/doc/:

```
texlive-fonts-extra-doc (2017.20180305-2) [universe]
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (2017.20180305-1)
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-humanities-doc (2017.20180305-2) [universe]
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-humanities
texlive-latex-base-doc (2017.20180305-1)
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-extra-doc (2017.20180305-2) [universe]
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended-doc (2017.20180305-1)
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-metapost-doc (2017.20180305-1)
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-metapost
texlive-pictures-doc (2017.20180305-1)
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pictures
texlive-pstricks-doc (2017.20180305-2) [universe]
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-pstricks
texlive-publishers-doc (2017.20180305-2) [universe]
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-publishers
texlive-science-doc (2017.20180305-2) [universe]
    TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-science
```